# Disable conditional formatting rules without deleting them

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheets document that is shared to other users.  The spreadsheet contains a lot of conditional formatting rules that add significantly to formula re-calculation times.

I would like to temporarily disable, not delete, some of the rules at times when they are not needed, to improve performance, but I don't see a way.

Is it possible in Google Sheets to temporarily disable conditional formatting rules without using a helper cell?

Answer (score 1):

- there isn't such functionality to switch off conditional formatting but you can do so by inserting **`'`** in front of the formula:

  [image: 0]

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented custom formatting where the formula uses an ON/OFF field value to start so something like this:

=if($I$35 <> "OFF", )

Not sure if it helps but thought I would throw it out there